# Star-shaped proof complex

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we formally prove that a convex set is star-shaped, and how to exhibit a non-convex set which is star-shaped? Also that an open star-shaped set is a region?

I guess its easily proven geometrically that one can have two arbitrary points in the open set which can be connected, hence, star-shaped, same goes with the definition of a region, but I struggle with formal arguments...

Comment: Can you state the formal definitions of convex and of star-shaped?

Comment: @LeeMosher for the star shaped, a subset s in the complex plane is star-shaped if there exists a in s such that [a,z] is in s for any z in s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a convex region, every point can "see" every other point (because every segment between two points in your set is also in your set), so you can choose an arbitrary base point as the center of your star and show your convex region is star-shaped from there.

To give an example of a non-convex region that is star-shaped, think about a filled in 5-point start where you choose your base point at the center

Comment: the star makes sense. but could you also help me with the argument on it being a region?